# Can I provide package parameters using Install-Package?

Tags: powershell, package-management, oneget, windows-package-manager

I know I can install packages on Windows Package Management with eg:

```
Get-PackageSource -Provider chocolatey
Install-Package -Name win32-openssh
```

But is there a way to provide package params? Eg packages like `win32-openssh` have options when they're installed via Chocolatey, **how can I provide package params using `Install-Package`?** Eg, something like:

```
Install-Package -Name win32-openssh -params '"/SSHServerFeature /KeyBasedAuthenticationFeature"'
```

PS. I know I could install the package directly via chocolatey - that's not my question.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this? I'd like to pass parameters to the git installation (like --params='/GitOnlyOnPath /NoAutoCrlf /NoShellIntegration'), or specify custom installation directories, and keep falling back to caling choco manually.

Comment: @stijn Nope, hence no answers below! Upmod it for visibility if you want.